# C program, make user to type multiple dynamic inputs in one line

Tags: c, scanf

How can I take one line dynamic input like this -> 1 4 3 5 of course, It can be done with this approach ->

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &variable[0], &variable[1], &variable[2], &variable[3]);
```

In this example, I am taking only 4 inputs...

**But my question is, how can I make it dynamic and work for a random number?**

```
// Sample Input
3 // number of rows
5 // number of columns

// 2d array with dynamic input
1 4 3 5 97
5 6 7 4 51
2 9 8 3 0
```

Comment: You can create the format string dynamically, but it's not possible to pass the variable number of arguments dynamically.

Comment: What does *"in one line"* mean, why is it important? Is it ok to write a multi-line function, which you can then call "in one line"?

Comment: I think he's referring to the inputs being in one line, not the C code.

Comment: @Barmar correct

Comment: re: title: "make user to..." Fortunately, we are still in a time when programs cannot **make** a user comply with a program's requirements. So, the task falls to the coder to write code that can handle incalcitrant users... Accept this and start by checking the return value from `scanf()`...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I think you're nitpicking poor wording by someone who doesn't speak English fluently. They just want to process the input on one line.

Comment: @Barmar "Nitpicking"? Captivation with the ever-shifting 'values' of SO is the reason I'm still here... Sometimes it's '_good_' to point out that `scanf()` returns an important value, and sometimes it's '_acceptable_' to provide answers that completely disregard the importance of "validating user input". Funny world...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I must have misunderstood your earlier point about "forcing" the user. It didn't seem like you were talking about validating, but somehow reaching through the screen and grabbing the user's hand.

Comment: @Barmar Your answer below doesn't confirm that `scanf()` successfully assigned the input value, either... I've had my wrists slapped, here on SO, for misspelling a word in a comment in code... Funny world...

Comment: Perhaps start with stopping using scanf, as outlined here https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to read each array entry.

```
int rows, cols;
if (scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols) != 2) {
    printf("Unable to read rows and cols\n");
    exit(1);
}
int variable[cols];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &variable[j]) != 1) {
            printf("Unable to process input\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    // do something with the variable array
}
```

Note that `scanf()` doesn't make a distinction between different types of whitespace that separate tokens. So this will read all the numbers on the same line, different lines, or a mixture.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I added error checking